# Visio freezes on Surface Pro 2

Tags: freeze, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-visio, microsoft-surface

**Scenario**:  Visio 2010 in Windows 8.1, or a Surface Pro 2 with all of the current updates.

**Problem**:  Visio 2010 starts without issue, but as soon as you try to open a new template, or a document, it freezes

**Tried so far**:

- visio.exe /safe  = works, but not a viable option going forward
- repair install of visio - no luck
- research

**Oddest part - potential hint**:  Some research pointed me to the Touch Screen and Handwriting service causing the issue.  Sure enough, stopping that service will restore functionality to Visio.  Obviously this is not a viable option going forward.

**Other items of note**

- Nothing in the event log relating to visio, or office in any way
- the user has the "type" keyboard
- the user makes use of the surface pro 2 dock
- Enterprise version of Windows
- User reports this problem started to happen after the last batch of updates (but with 100+ updates all happening, troubleshooting them all is out of the question I fear.

Comment: They installed 100 updates since fhe problem started? I find that hard to believe

Comment: You say you have "all current updates", but is that just for Windows, or did you also apply all the Visio 2010 updates as well?

Comment: @Ramhound, I think we had a miscommunication there.  The user hadnt installed updates in a while, then, after their last batch (a little over 100 in total) and restart, they said is when the problem started.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 All updates including all microsoft products.

Comment: @francisswest - So have the user start with updates to Office and/or Visio.

Answer (score 0):

You're heading in the direction of a bug in a patch, which could be right, but I would suggest you reinstall the OS.  It's a simple concrete action, can that should either solve the problem or confirm it.

- Reinstall OS
- Install Visio & confirm proper function
- Install all updates (or in batches if you're willing)
- Test Visio & open a ticket with MS if the same issue happens

Answer (score 0):

I found that going to Task Manager and ending the touchscreen and handwriting service fixes the problem.  Looking for a long term solution.